# F5 IRule,Generate New Alerts

Tags: f5, web-application-firewall

I use F5 and I have an issue.
I want to build an Irule that check the following scenario

```
url=="domain.com" and Content-Length(of the request) > 400
then
alert(response)
```

Is it possible to create this Irule?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your alert action desire is (simulated here with the # take action block), but the rule is pretty simple:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { ([HTTP::host] eq "domain.com") and ([HTTP::header Content-Length] > 400) } {
     # take action
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly mean you want to use alertd to generate an email or SNMP trap? If so, then as long as alertd is looking for the error you put in the log, that would take the alert action.